Understanding the role of "durch" in a deeper linguistic sense in Nominaliserung

Aufgabe: Verbinden Sie die Sätze mit den angegebenen Konnektoren

Auch leichte Kunstoffobjekte sinken auf den Meeresboden. Die Verwitterung verändert ihr spezifisches Gewicht. (Aufgrund)
Aufgrund der Verändernug ihres spezifischen Gewichts durch Verwitterung sinken auch leichte Kunstoffobjekte auf den Meeresboden


I want to understand the usage of durch in the above. My teacher had told me before that durch functions not really as a preposition here.
Could someone give me a more detailed explanation with terms I can use to search for more information about this? Thanks.

Durch plus noun indicates the cause/reason of some attribute. Often it starts a sentence and the effect follows:
Durch Starkregen kommt es zu Überflutungen... By heavy rainfall flooding ensues...
Durch den Lärm angelockt... attracted by the noise...
Durch die Sperrung der Maierstrasse, kommt es zu Staus.... Due to the closure of the Maier-street..
Es ist mit Verdunkelung durch Zugvögel zu rechnen ... One may expect darker skies caused by migrating birds...
The bad side effect of "aufgrund" is that the reason is packed into a noun and the effect fills the main sentence. The result is some sort of speak in technical manuals. So the "aufgrund" is usually found in written texts. The standard speaker would likely split it into two sentences: Die Verwitterung verändert das spezifische Gewicht von leichten Kunstoffobjekten. Dadurch sinken auch sie auf den Meersboden.

It is a preposition. But the adverbial it leads isn't free floating but bound to the noun phrase

die Veränderung (ihres spezifischen Gewichts) durch Verwitterung

Such adverbials that are bound to noun phrases are very common in German:

der Bus in die Stadt
die Linde auf dem Dorfplatz
das Buch für Kinder
der Vortrag über den Bergbau im Ruhrgebiet

The latter example has those adverbials stacked.
